# make a hwid login in c++ (mulitbyte)

Tags: c++

hello guys i tried to make a hwid login for a app. The problem is when i compile all the code i have this error.

Error C2676 binary '==': 'std::basic_string,std::allocator>' does not define this operator or a conversion to a type acceptable to the predefined operator

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <intrin.h>
#include <TlHelp32.h>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;
vector<string> serial;
vector<string> windows;

void loadserial()
{
    serial.push_back("1731602307");
}

void loadWindows()
{
    windows.push_back("29548");
}

int main()
{
    TCHAR volumeName[MAX_PATH + 1] = { 0 };
    TCHAR fileSystemName[MAX_PATH + 1] = { 0 };
    DWORD serialNumber = 0;
    DWORD maxComponentLen = 0;
    DWORD fileSystemFlags = 0;
    if (GetVolumeInformation(
        _T("C:\\"),
        volumeName,
        ARRAYSIZE(volumeName),
        &serialNumber,
        &maxComponentLen,
        &fileSystemFlags,
        fileSystemName,
        ARRAYSIZE(fileSystemName)))
    {
    }

    int cpuinfo[4] = { 0, 0, 0, 0 };
    __cpuid(cpuinfo, 0);
    char16_t hash = 0;
    char16_t* ptr = (char16_t*)(&cpuinfo[0]);
    for (char32_t i = 0; i < 8; i++)
        hash += ptr[i];

    while (true)
    {
        if (find(serial.begin(), serial.end(), serialNumber) != serial.end())
        {
            std::cout << "nice you are in our auth system!!";
        }
        else
        {
            std::cout << "you arent in the whitelist ;(";
        }
    }
    return(0);
}
```

Comment: Your error message is complaining about `operator==` but `==` appears nowhere in this code. So you should tell us which line produces this compiler error message, because it's certainly not obvious. I'm guessing that your real code is different from the code you've posted or you've quoted the error message incorrectly.

Comment: ***Error C2676 binary '==': 'std::basic_string,std::allocator>' does not define this operator or a conversion to a type acceptable to the predefined operator*** I don't think you gave the full error message from the Output tab. This looks more of a reduced error message you get in the errors list.

Comment: Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error C2676 binary '==': 'std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>>' does not define this operator or a conversion to a type acceptable to the predefined operator serial C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.25.28610\include\xutility 4640

Comment: ***Severity Code Description*** That is the Errors list. The output tab never shows that part.

Comment: i cant upload it it has a lot of words...

Comment: You may want to look at the documentation for [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-getvolumeinformationa](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-getvolumeinformationa) the `DWORD` serial number is an OS assigned number when the disk is formatted (meaning it likely can be duplicated) and not the manufacturer serial string which is queried from the drive itself (much harder to duplicate / requires manufacturer specific information to read and alter).

Answer (score 1):

OK, now it's clear

```
find(serial.begin(), serial.end(), serialNumber)
```

`serial` is a `vector<string>` but `serialNumber` is a `DWORD`. You can't use `find` to look for a DWORD in a vector of strings. I guess you need to convert the DWORD to a string first, or maybe you could change serial to a `vector<DWORD>`.

And as drescherjm says get into the habit of looking at the output tab for your error messages, it's much more useful than the error list (which for some reason microsoft insist on showing you first).

Comment: i dont know how to do that, i tried but i have more errors

Comment: To convert a DWORD to a string just use the `std::to_string` function. Simply `find(serial.begin(), serial.end(), to_string(serialNumber))` should work.